# Распаковка большого zip-архива, OutOfMemoryException, ZipArchiveInputStream, ByteArrayInputStream и попытка не зависеть от объема архива

Tags: java, память, heap

Стоит задача считывать большие zip-архивы (от 500Мб и выше).

Есть наброски кода, который должен это делать. Но при попытке получаю:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryException: Java heap space.

Разбираюсь. Подозреваю, что надо оптимизировать код или сам алгоритм.
Буду признателен за подсказки.

Собственно код:

```
inputStream = (ByteArrayInputStream) fileDataHandler.getContent();
byte archive[] = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
String docPath = doc.getUri().replace('\\', '/');
if(docPath.endsWith("/")) {
   docPath = docPath.substring(0, docPath.length()-1);
}
ZipArchiveEntry ze;
Map<String, byte[]> files = new HashMap<String, byte[]>();
ZipArchiveInputStream zis = null;
try{
   zis = new ZipArchiveInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(archive), "cp886", true);
   while((ze = zis.getNextZipEntry()) != null) {
      if(!ze.isDirectory()) {
         byte[] toByteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(zis);
         files.put(docPath + "/" ze.getName().replace('\\', '/'), toByteArray);

         //some checking for file validating

      }
   }
} catch(IOException ioe) {
```

Comment: А не пробовали под виртуальную машину больше памяти выделять? Xms Xmx ?

Comment: вам обязательно держать все данные из архива в памяти одновременно?

Comment: Пока не определился: возможно, придется держать, чтобы проверять размер и хэш архива перед началом распаковки.

Comment: Здесь, думаю, надо изменить решение, тк надо не зависеть от объема архива - ведь может быть и больше.

Answer (score 2):

Сложно придумать задачу, при которой вам обязательно нужно держать весь архив в памяти. Вот так, например, можно посчитать хеш от всех файлов в архиве:

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("archive.zip");
MessageDigest sha256 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

ZipArchiveEntry ze;
ZipArchiveInputStream zis = null;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
try {
    zis = new ZipArchiveInputStream(file, "cp886", true);
    while ((ze = zis.getNextZipEntry()) != null) {
        if (!ze.isDirectory()) {
            int read;
            while ((read = zis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
                sha256.update(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        }
    }
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    System.out.println("error");
}

byte[] hash = sha256.digest();
```

Что бы посчитать/проверить что-то другое, вам придется снова открывать файл с архивом. Посчитать размер файлов также можно без затрат памяти изменив код в середине:

```
int fileSize = 0;
int read;
while ((read = zis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
    fileSize += read;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ. Хорошо. Допустим, я буду считать хэш указанным способом. Тогда можно ли воспользоваться такой схемой: zip -> InputStream -> BufferedInputStream -> ZipArchiveInputStream ?

Comment: @AlekseyKrekotnev Вы хотите меньше читать из диска? На больших файлах вы не увидите разницы.

Comment: Извините, не совсем понял Вас. Считать с диска придется часто, тк архивы будут постоянно обновляться. Или вопрос в другом?

Comment: Вы неправильно понимаете как работает `BufferedInputStream`. Если вы укажете ему размер буффера 100мб, то он считает первые 100 мб в память, и будет отдавать понемногу, при вызове методов `Read`. Если размер файла будет 101 мб, потом эти 100мб удалятся из памяти, и на их место прочитается кусок в 1 мб. При повторном чтении из диска вам все равно придется снова читать первые 100мб.

Comment: На что опираться тогда, если архивы будут постоянно меняться по размеру, содержанию и имени? Я не могу задать какой-то фикс, тк не имею информации заранее.

Comment: @AlekseyKrekotnev можно скопировать архив, который вы собрались обрабатывать, во временный файл. И работать с ним оттуда

Comment: Благодарю. Думаю, так будет вернее.